# Projections on a subset that can be be split into a finite union of linear subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, vector-spaces

Apologies for a possibly confusing question. I would appreciate any insight into this.

Suppose I have a Banach space $\mathcal{X}$. There is a proper closed subset  $A \subset \mathcal{X}$ (not a linear subspace), and I am interested in considering projections onto this $A$. For any $x \in \mathcal{X}$ let me denote by $x_A$ its projection on $A$.

I know that $A$ can be represented as 
$$A=B_1 \cup B_2 \cup \ldots \cup B_m,$$

where each $B_i$ is a closed linear subspace in $X$ such that each $B_i$ and $B_j$,  $i \neq j$,

$$B_i \cap B_j = (B_i \cup B_j) \backslash (Int(B_i)\cup Int(B_j)).$$

That is, the intersection between two different $B_i$ and $B_j$ is “small” (only on the boundary).

For any $x \in \mathcal{X}$ let me denote by $x_{B_i}$ its projection onto $B_i$. Let $x_B$ denote the elements among $x_{B_1}, \ldots, x_{B_m}$ that delivers the best predictor among $x_{B_1}, \ldots, x_{B_m}$.

I am interested in the following question:

1) *Under what conditions can I conclude that $(x_{A})_B$ (which is of course the same as $x_A$) coincides with $x_B$?*

2) *Has something like this appeared in some applications?*

Comment: How do you define projections (even onto a subspace) in Banach space?  ({\em Hint:} generally, a projection is defined as being "onto one subspace along another subspace."  See Halmos's book on vector spaces.).

Comment: What is $B$? In particular, what is the space for which $(x_A)_B$, $x_B$ are the projections onto that space?

Comment: @avs: I define $x_A \equiv \arg \min_{y \in A} \|x-y\|$

Comment: @William: there is no $B$, but $x_B≡\arg \min_{x_{B_i},i=1,…,m}\|x−x_{B_i}\|$

Comment: I kind of figured out now that the question to 1) will always be "True under the described conditions".